# Is a 44" chimney too short to create a sufficient draft?

Tags: fireplace, chimney, carbon-monoxide

I put a wood-burning stove in a motorhome but realized that the chimney might not have enough height for an adequate draft. I've got a single double wall stove pipe going straight through the roof with a flashing, collar and cap at the top. The pipe is 24" inside and 20" on the outside.

I can't realistically make the chimney any higher while moving as I'm already at a total height of around 12'. However, I can add on about 50" while stationary.

1. Will the 44" chimney create a sufficient draft? (the top of the chimney is at 12' above the ground)
2. Will a 94" chimney create a sufficient draft?
3. Will the 44" chimney create a sufficient draft while in motion at highway speeds?

EDIT: where I live the temperatures in winter at night are between 32 and 42 F and up to 60 F during the day.

EDIT2: Wood burning stoves are is actually a very common thing in the tiny house community. For example see the thousand+ with one installed here [link](https://www.google.com/search?q=tiny%20house%20wood%20stove&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS821US822&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiEwZ2uqezkAhVBHzQIHXBoApYQ_AUIEygC&biw=1973&bih=967). It's a real, practical question. If it violates DOT regs, please cite a specific case. Wood burning stoves in MHs are super common and I'd definitely like to know if this is illegal. Of course, living in a tiny house is illegal where I am, but we as a community are trying to stay within the law where possible.

Comment: While I can't comment with confidence on the height required for good draft (other than suggesting you check the stove manufacturer's instructions), I will express my concern about a wood-fired stove in a motorhome: fire hazard, carbon monoxide...

Comment: @JimmyFix-it Totally second you on the risk of CO poisoning. I've got a smoke and CO detector, but a properly functioning chimney should do the trick.

Comment: You won’t be using this while driving will you?

Comment: @EdBeal I don't drive it that much. Its stationary 99% of the time. I asked the draft while driving more for curiosity since the speed would create a vacuum in the chimney. The physics of speeding up and slowing down are more interesting/dangerous, as they would produce irregular airflow. That wouldn't be good, but I'd like a second opinion on exactly what to expect.

Comment: No it still depends on any ridge and the type of cap. Growing up in a construction company on the west coast you need a cap with a rotary cap. But even though that type of cap would work even a few inches above a flat roof it may be a violation of law for moving vechicles.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this will violate Department  of transportation rules   Asking members to validate an idea that has been answered as dangerous and may lead to loss of life in an accident.

Comment: I met a machinist once in Canada who had made and installed a wood stove in his camper van, and sometimes travelled with it lit. Sounded like a Darwin Award contender.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this topic involves a moving vehicle....

Comment: @EdBeal I'm well within legal height limits. Even with the chimney installed I'm at ~12' in height. Also please cite a specific rule that this violates. I've already stated that the part about moving while burning it is more a curiosity not a practical problem. The practical problem is what height chimney will create a draft. Please answer if you know.

Answer (score 1):

Even asking about draft at highway travelling speeds invokes thoughts about the danger of keeping a wood fired unit burning while under way on a freeway. The whole idea sounds downright dangerous and fraught with risk.

The energy density of a propane bottle as opposed to hauling a pile of firewood also seems to vote against the idea of installing a wood stove in an RV.

Comment: There are many reasons I chose to install a wood-burning stove in a motorhome, but I totally understand why others would choose propane. One of the most important reasons is the lack of condensation since the wood-burning stove is self-contained and provides radiant heat. The condensation produced goes directly outside (ideally)